# Handling MultiValueDictKeyError on posting dateTime object to Django database

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to post two DateTime objects on my Django database.

#### models.py

```py
class Timesheet(models.Model):
    task_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    task_description = models.TextField(null=True)
    PRIORITY_STATUS = [
        ('H','High'),
        ('M','Medium'),
        ('L','Low'),
    ]
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PRIORITY_STATUS)
    starting_time = models.DateTimeField()
    ending_time = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.task_title)

    class timeSheetForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model=Timesheet
            fields=['project','user','task_title','task_description','priority','starting_time','ending_time']
```

#### forms.py:

```py
class timeSheetForm(forms.Form):
    #other fields
    starting_time = forms.DateTimeField(widget=AdminSplitDateTime())
    ending_time = forms.DateTimeField(widget=AdminSplitDateTime())
```

#### views.py:

```py
def memberDash(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        newTimeSheet = Timesheet()
        newTimeSheet.project = Project.objects.get(pk=request.POST["project"])
        newTimeSheet.user =  User.objects.get(pk=request.POST["user"])
        newTimeSheet.task_title = request.POST["task_title"]
        newTimeSheet.task_description = request.POST["task_description"]
        newTimeSheet.priority = request.POST["priority"]
        newTimeSheet.starting_time = request.POST["starting_time"]
        newTimeSheet.ending_time = request.POST["ending_time"]

        newTimeSheet.save()

        return render(request,'timeSheetApp/dashboard.html')
    else:
        form = timeSheetForm()
    context={
        'form':form,
    }
    return render(request,'timeSheetApp/dashboard.html',context)
```

#### The template

```html
<form action="/memberDashboard/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="starting_time" class="col-lg-1 col-form-label">Start Time</label>
    {{form.starting_time}}
    <label for="ending_time" class="col-lg-1 col-form-label">End Time</label>
    {{form.ending_time}}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">                                        
        <strong>Create Time-Sheet</strong>
    </button>
</form>
```

On submission of this form, the MultiValueDictKeyError is being raised, and some second pair of eyes would be of great help here, as I am not getting what am I missing here. A newbie to Django, so sorry if posting a silly question.

The **error log file**:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/memberDashboard/

Django Version: 2.2
Python Version: 3.7.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'timeSheetApp']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py" in __getitem__
  78.             list_ = super().__getitem__(key)

During handling of the above exception ('starting_time'), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "E:\TimeSheet\timeSheet\timeSheetApp\views.py" in memberDash
  19.         newTimeSheet.starting_time.date = request.POST["starting_time"].date()

File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py" in __getitem__
  80.             raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)

Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /memberDashboard/
Exception Value: 'starting_time'
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `forms.SplitDateTimeField` if you want to use a multi value widget:

```py
from django.forms import SplitDateTimeField

class timeSheetForm(forms.Form):
    #other fields
    starting_time = forms.SplitDateTimeField(widget=AdminSplitDateTime())
    ending_time = forms.SplitDateTimeField(widget=AdminSplitDateTime())
```

This is because this widget uses two form widgets under the hood and the field needs to know how to put the two widget values into one field value to be saved into one model field. More information in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#multivaluefield).

Comment: Thanks @Melvyn, and yeah I  knew about this widget sneaking two other widgets under the hood and even after using forms.SplitDateTimeField, it is raising the same MultiValueDictKeyError(key) exception.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was initializing the modal class itself instead of the ModalForm.
In *views.py* should be:

```
newTimeSheet = timeSheetForm()
#inplace of newTimeSheet = TimeSheet()
```